# error finding class path file in jar file

Tags: java, jar, xsd

I am gettine error when running my java application. My application is bundled in a .jar file. It means xsd file is in the .jar file.

Error:

```
class path resource [classpath*:myschema.xsd] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

source of the error:

```
@Value("classpath*:myschema.xsd")
private Resource xsdFile;

public boolean validateXML()() throws IOException {
    boolean isValidXMLFile = false;

    Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File(xmlDataFile));
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = null;
    File outXsdFile = new File("autogenpath.xsd");
    InputStream is =xsdFile.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(outXsdFile);
    IOUtils.copy(is, out);

    try {
        schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(outXsdFile);
    } catch (SAXException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        isValidXMLFile = false;
        log.debug("Error reading schema " + e1.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(xmlFile);
        log.debug(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
        isValidXMLFile = true;

    } catch (SAXParseException e) {
        isValidXMLFile = false;
        log.debug(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
        log.debug("Reason\t\t: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        log.debug("Line Number \t: " + e.getLineNumber());
        log.debug("Column Number\t: " + e.getColumnNumber());
        log.debug("Public Id\t: " + e.getPublicId());
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        isValidXMLFile = false;
        log.debug(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
        log.debug("Reason\t: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    finally{
        try{
        out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    return isValidXMLFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing calls to

```
new File("...")
```

with

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("...")
```

or even

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceStream("...")
```

When you jar up your application, you need to ask the classloader to get the files for you.

Comment: I used getResourceAsStream() his is working for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
@Value("${classpath}/myschema.xsd")
private Resource xsdFile;
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I don't know why my class path resource shows something different but it has xsd file. But still fails to load